# How do I open a SQLite database from DocumentPicker in React Native using Expo

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I would like to open an existing SQLite database file inside Expo-SQLite. The file locates let's say somewhere in the device (e.g. device Documentsfolder), so that the user can open it via a DocumentPicker.
I'm having trouble getting the file that has been choosen from DocumentPicker into SQLite:

```
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker'
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'

openFile = () => {
    const res = DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync().then(result => {
            let db = SQLite.openDatabase(result.uri)
            console.log(db) //logs null
        })
}
```

I can assure that SQLite works while working internally, since

```
let db = SQLite.openDatabase('test.db')
```

let's me query SQL queries on `db`.

EDIT:

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'; 

        openFile = async() => {
        const localdb = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}$mylocal.db`;
        const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync();
        const copyResult = await FileSystem.copyAsync({from: result.uri,
                to: localdb 
            });

       let db = SQLite.openDatabase(localdb);
       console.log(db);
}
```

seemed to open the database file. However

```
await db.transaction((txn) => {
 txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Record', [],
 (txn, rs) => console.log(rs.rows),
 (error) => console.log(error)) })
```

outputs nothing.. I checked the database file with DB Browser for SQLite and everything seems fine with the file itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

Try with Expo Snack:
when you open the db pay attention to the path that was copied:

```
 let db = SQLite.openDatabase('sample1.db');
```

https://snack.expo.io/r1Tvwkm5S

Comment: The first solution gives me `unknown error (code 1294 SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT[1294]): Could not open database` error, after I'm trying to run a simple SELECT statement..

The second solution seems to open the database, but when I run `await db.transaction((txn) => {
        txn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Record', [], (txn, rs) => console.log(rs.rows), (error) => console.log(error))
    })`
it outputs nothing..

Comment: Check the SQL db file  and repost the code in question

Comment: Done so. I tested the database file with DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: Can you make expo snack sample with the file db from assets, I will try to copy and  pick the file from another location on Android device.

Comment: Do you mean like so? https://snack.expo.io/rkRJhZf9B
Sorry, it's the first time for me working with React Native/Expo/Snack so I'm kinda still learning^^

Comment: can you provide the file of db link for download.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/21777bd6c5f71c819f9f34abe653fcf520191027081613/ca228e

Comment: Updated answer with snack , tested on Android

Comment: thank you sir, this one seemed to work! And for rewriting the original file, do I have to copy the file back to `result.uri` from `pathToDownloadTo` ?

Comment: Yes if you want override the original.

Comment: I tried it with copyAsync and downloadAsync, but both restrict me writing the source file.. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this ? Or shoud I open up another question for that if I cannot find an answer myself?

Comment: Did you close the db before and may be askPermissions for write

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! I tried it with db._db.close() and with db.closed=true, but it didn't work. I also tried to ask permissions for Permissions.askAsync('camera') and Permissions.askAsync('cameraroll') as there is no explicit permission for storage, but this also did not work. My approach was `await FileSystem.copyAsync({from: pathToDownloadTo, to: fileUri})` which gives me `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Asample.db isn't writable`

Comment: i think it's problem to write to location that out of the app scope. did you think about another approach: make a browsing feature  to directory of local app/sql directory  scope with all files that were copied to it without overwriting the originals.

Comment: So basically I give the user the option to choose a file via DocumentPicker, but the file gets copied to app/sqlite directory. Then there will be a view for files in that app/sqlite directory? The problem I see is that: I wanted the user to be able to use the db file cross platform. There is an application for desktop which uses this exact same db file. The user could save the db file in a cloud storage and load it on both platforms.